# Equation system with alignment

Tags: matrices

I want to set up a linear equation system where the individual terms in each equation are aligned with the corresponding terms in the above. Currently, my attempt looks something like this:

```
\[ \begin{matrix}
a_{11}x_1 & + & a_{12}x_2 & = & y_1\\
a_{21}x_1 & + & a_{22}x_2 & = & y_2
\end{matrix}
\]
```

This does the alignment job just fine, but I haven't been able to make the spaces small enough that it looks neat. Using array instead of matrix doesn't seem to change it. 
Any ideas?

Comment: since `matrix` is defined you must have presumably loaded `amsmath` in which case, use `align` (or perhaps `alignat`)

Comment: Yeah, I tried using align, but with multiple alignment tabs (&), it seems to expand the equation to textwidth, separating the two "columns" as much as it can. I don't know 
    "alignat".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `array` or with `systeme`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array} % for the first example
\usepackage{systeme} % for the second example

\begin{document}

With \verb|array|
\[
\left\lbrace
  % some local refinements
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \begin{array}{c >{{}}c<{{}} c >{{}}c<{{}} c}
  a_{11}x_1 & + & a_{12}x_2 & = & y_1\\
  a_{21}x_1 & + & a_{22}x_2 & = & y_2\\[.3ex]
  \end{array}
\right.
\]
and with \verb|\systeme|
\[
\syssubstitute{{A}{a_{11}}{B}{a_{12}}{C}{a_{21}}{D}{a_{22}}}
\systeme[x_1x_2]{
Ax_1 + Bx_2 = y_1,
Cx_1 + Dx_2 = y_2
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `array`-based solution may be simplified by setting `\arraycolsep0pt` after `\[`: that way, all six `@{}` directives in the setup of the `array` environment can be omitted.

Comment: @Mico Done some refinements

Comment: I had already up-voted your answer before you applied the refinements. :-)

Comment: Is there a manual for the `\array` package? Where can I find it?
It's a bit confusing that the `array` environment was already defined by amsmath. I'd like to know more about the differences between the two.

Comment: @JumpCow -- if you are using a tex live installation, at a command prompt, type `texdoc array` and you will get the documentation for the `array` package as a pdf file.  the basic `array` is defined in the latex core, not in `amsmath`.  if you look at `texdoc lshort`, the `array` environment is described in section 3.6.

Answer (score 1):

Here, a `\tabularVectorstack` is also an option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\begin{document}
\[ 
\setstacktabulargap{0pt}
\TABbinary
\tabularVectorstack{rcrcr}{
a_{11}x_1 & + & a_{12}x_2 & = & y_1\\
a_{21}x_1 & + & a_{22}x_2 & = & y_2
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]